# Why does a network volume have a "-1" at the end after upgrading to Lion?

Tags: macos, airport, network, nas

I have a USB hard drive attached to an Airport Extreme called "Webb Family Network Storage."

After upgrading to Lion, about 50% of the time, this volume will mount with a "-1" on the end, showing up as "/Volumes/Nic's Airport Extreme/Webb Family Network Storage-1/"

Normally this wouldn't be a huge deal, but a few apps that use Java or Air that interact directly with the paths (such as Eye-Fi's Upload Center or CrashPlan) will detect that the volume is missing and I'll either have to re-configure them to use the new "-1" path or reboot the machine and hope that it connects using the "old" path.

Is there a workaround for this? Some sort of cache I can clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the drive is ejected, does the directory `/Volumes/Nic's Airport Extreme/Webb Family Network Storage/` exist? If so, move it to the desktop (so you save any contents, if any) and reboot.

Comment: Yes - that folder exists even if the drive isn't mounted. I'll give that a try when I get in front of my laptop. I hope this fixes it.